# How does magnatic flux conservation work for semi-infinite solenoid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

From the equation of $\Phi_B$ for a region
$$\Phi_B=\int_Vd^3r \nabla\cdot B=0$$
, it gave a sense of magnetic flux conservation, just like electric flux in a region of space without charge.

However, consider an infinite solenoid cut in half. It's easy to see that the magnetic flux  at the cutted open surface was only half of that inside.

How's that possible? where did the magnetic flux go in at the open of semi-infinite solenoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"where did the magnetic flux go in at the open of semi-infinite solenoid?"

It escaped through the curved surface of the solenoid near the geometrical "North pole" end of the solenoid. Roughly half the flux that enters the half-solenoid from the other half leaves the half-solenoid through its open end, the other half leaves through the curved surface.